# Trying to find composite annotation by searching for one of its base annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I'm writing a Java framework that allows consumers to write POJOs with custom annotations. The framework will cater to processing depending on the annotation type declared for each field.

In the framework I've created a base domain annotation:

```java
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
public @interface BaseDomain {}
```

And then `StringDomain.java` and `FloatDomain.java` which are annotated with `@BaseDomain`:

```java
@BaseDomain
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
public @interface StringDomain {}
```

```java
@BaseDomain
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
public @interface FloatDomain {}
```

Consumers of the framework will be allowed to write their own annotations as long as those new annotation interfaces are themselves annotated by `@BaseDomain`, similar to `FloatDomain` and `StringDomain`.

For instance, a consumer could create an annotation named `Username` which has `StringDomain` as a "parent".

Sample of a consumer's POJO:

```java
public class ItemDTO {

  @StringDomain
  public String text;

}
```

Inside the framework I can find `BaseDomain` annotations present on the field using:

```java
import org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils;

final BaseDomain annotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(field, BaseDomain.class);
```

But how can I determine that the returned `BaseDomain` is was actually part of `StringDomain`?

In normal inheritance I could get `BaseDomain` and check its type to know that its an instance of `StringDomain`.

```java
System.out.println(annotation.annotationType().getSimpleName());
BaseDomain
```

Comment: In theory, simple `annotation.annotationType().getSimpleName()` prints you "StringDomain" in that case

Comment: `annotation.annotationType().getSimpleName()` is printing `BaseDomain`

Comment: Yeah, you can't directly use `AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(field, BaseDomain.class)` since it is looking specifically for the `@BaseDomain`, so you may need to find all (!) annotations of the field and then check if any of those annotations themselves are annotated with `@BaseDomain` instead. Let me know if it's clear enough, or it's better to provide a snippet

Comment: @bobbyrne01 Have you resolved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

#### Before Spring 5.2

You can use the `getAnnotations` method to find all non-meta present on the supplied element.

Either get all direct annotations:

```java
var field = ItemDto.class.getField("text");
var annotation = AnnotationUtils.getAnnotations(field)[0];

System.out.println(annotation.annotationType().getSimpleName());
```

> ```
> StringDomain
> ```

However, this method is deprecated as of 5.2

#### Spring 5.2 and newer

The replacement for the deprecated method is MergedAnnotations API ([source](http://www.java2s.com/example/java-src/pkg/org/springframework/core/annotation/annotationutils-1c465.html)).

```java
var field = ItemDto.class.getField("text");
MergedAnnotations.from(field)
        .stream()
        .filter(a -> a.getType().isAssignableFrom(StringDomain.class))
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(a -> System.out.println(a.getType().getSimpleName()));

System.out.println(annotations);
```

> ```
> StringDomain
> ```

Or check whether the particular one is present:

```java
var field = ItemDto.class.getField("text");
var hasStringDomain = MergedAnnotations.from(field)
    .isDirectlyPresent(StringDomain.class);

System.out.println(hasStringDomain);
```

> ```
> true
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In the given scenario, since the BaseDomain annotation is used as a meta-annotation (annotation on another annotation), you can determine if the returned BaseDomain annotation is part of StringDomain by checking if the field's annotation type is annotated with StringDomain. Here's how you can achieve this:

```
final BaseDomain annotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(field, BaseDomain.class);

if (annotation != null) {
Annotation[] annotations = annotation.annotationType().getAnnotations();

for (Annotation ann : annotations) {
    if (ann.annotationType() == StringDomain.class) {
        // The returned BaseDomain is part of StringDomain
        // Perform the desired processing for StringDomain annotation
        // ...
        break;
    }
}
```

}